# Postgres WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 59

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg

I'm using the pg:transfer utility recommended by Heroku to push and pull databases. For example:

```
heroku pg:transfer -f postgres://username:password@localhost/database-name -t postgres://user-name:password@host-name/database-name --confirm app-name
```

I have been able to do it successfully, but each time it states that error were ignored at the end of the transfer:

```
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 59
```

Do I need to worry about this?

**EDIT:**

I went through my output and it seems to error on each table. It seems to drop the sequence, and then throw an error saying it does not exist.

```
pg_restore: dropping SEQUENCE OWNED BY roles_id_seq 
pg_restore: dropping SEQUENCE roles_id_seq 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 170; 1259 35485 SEQUENCE roles_id_seq postgres 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: sequence "roles_id_seq" does not exist Command was: DROP SEQUENCE public.roles_id_seq;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to silence these non-error errors?

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that what is happening is that it is running a "clean" restore which means it drops the previous objects just to be sure and then recreates them.

If these are your only errors they are entirely safe to ignore.  Too bad the toolchain is not smart enough to add an IF EXISTS to the drop commands.